# XSLT replacement with dynamic values?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a xsl template which can replace some xml values.
Now I want these values to be dynamically generated by my code.

```
Transformer trans = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("foo.xsl"));
trans.transform(new StreamSource(new File("foo.xml"), new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
```

How can I acchive eg replacing the name ONLY where id=1? And moreover provide that id dynamically by javacode, not hardcoded?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<my:accounts xmlns:my="http://myns">
<my:account>
<my:name>alex</my:name>
<my:id>1</my:id>
</my:account>
<my:account>
<my:name>Fiona</my:name>
<my:id>2</my:id>
</my:account>
</my:accounts>
```

This replaces all names:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="http://myns">

 <xsl:param name="propertyName" select="'alex'"/>

      <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='account']/*[local-name()='name']/text()[.='{$propertyName}']">
       <xsl:text>johndoe</xsl:text>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="http://myns">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pId" select="2"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="my:name/text()">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="../../my:id = $pId">johndoe</xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<my:accounts xmlns:my="http://myns">
    <my:account>
        <my:name>alex</my:name>
        <my:id>1</my:id>
    </my:account>
    <my:account>
        <my:name>Fiona</my:name>
        <my:id>2</my:id>
    </my:account>
</my:accounts>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<my:accounts xmlns:my="http://myns">
   <my:account>
      <my:name>alex</my:name>
      <my:id>1</my:id>
   </my:account>
   <my:account>
      <my:name>johndoe</my:name>
      <my:id>2</my:id>
   </my:account>
</my:accounts>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Use of a global-scope `<xsl:param>`. Although a default value is set, this is overriden by the value specified by the invoker of the transformation.
2. Do note that the question how to specify the value of an external parameter to the transformation has different answers for differen xslt processors (vendors). You need to read the documentation of the specific XSLT processor you are using to get this answer for your particular case.

Comment: Really a great example, it works. BUT what if I change the id to a string, let's say `<my:id>test</my:id>` and `<xsl:param name="pId" select="test"/>` this does NOT work. What am I missing here?

Comment: @membersound, You are welcome. And yes, you must specify a string literal, otherwise it is interpreted as a node-name.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a parameter in your xsl stylesheet

```
<xsl:param name="id" select="'0'"/>
```

And then pass it as a Parameter in Java:

trans.setParameter("id", "1");

Would that work for you? or do you want to pass multiple parameters?

Something like what is refered [here - The Transformer Class](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/java_xslt_ch5/index.html?page=4)

This xsl works, but it is in 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="http://myns">
<xsl:param name="id" select="'1'"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='account'][*:id=$id]/*[local-name()='name']/text()">
   <xsl:text>johndoe</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Try @Dimitre Novatchev's seems like it works and it is 1.0 compliant